# Are * and + equivalent to, respectively, && and || on Boolean operands?

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

a[8] is an array of booleans. I am trying to calculate a boolean expression looking like the following.

```
bool a[8];
.....
bool result=a[0]*(a[3]+a[6]*(a[4]+a[7]*a[5]))+a[1]*(a[6]*a[3]+a[4]+a[7]*a[5])+a[2]*(a[5]+a[7]*(a[4]+a[6]*a[3]));
```

The expression is long, but conceptually nothing complicated. The only bug is, it seems the result is different when I replace the * in the expression with && (in both cases I am expecting a logical AND) or replace + with || (expecting logical OR).

I am not sure which ones would be correct, the boolean operators or the mathematical notations of multiplication, addition etc. Worse, none give any error, i.e. the compiler is happy with both. Which one is safer and correct?

Comment: @EdHeal: Please write answers in the answer area.

Comment: Upvoted for its sheer intriguing peculiarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are *almost* the same for `bool` operands. But there are subtle differences:

1. `*` and `+` will widen the `bool` type arguments to `int` types.
2. The type of the expression `a || b` is `bool`, whereas `a + b` is `int`. Ditto for `&&` and `*`.
3. `*` and `+` are not sequencing points, whereas `&&` and `||` are.
4. `*` and `+` are not short-circuited, whereas `&&` and `||` are.
5. They occupy very different positions in the operator precedence table. So substitution is not straightforward.
6. If `a` is a `bool`, and `b` is also a `bool` but is not initialised then the behaviour of `a || b` is defined, but `a + b` is *undefined* since a `bool` *can* contain a trap representation in C++. Similar expressions can be conjured for `&&` and `*`.
7. A very long chain of `a + b + c + ...` could overflow the `int` type, the behaviour of which is undefined.

(3) means that `a++ * a++` is undefined behaviour but `a++ || a++` is not.

(Not really relevant here but worth noting: note that `&&` and `||` lose their short circuiting property if they are overloaded).

Comment: So logically speaking they're not ;)

Comment: Yes, "logical" is hard to explain. I've simply tinned the term.

Comment: Also, an overflow could cause a flip from logical 1 to 0.

Comment: @LogicStuff: formally a truck load of undefined behaviour! Pinched that.

Comment: "lose their short circuiting property" is a bit confusing. Overloaded `&&` and `||` do not short circuit, but that has no effect on the builtin versions, which always short circuit.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to short-circuiting in logical operators, which does not make a difference here, the crucial difference to explain change in behavior is [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

When you replace `*` with `&&`, or `+` with `||`, the order of precedence changes: `*` has *higher* precedence than `+`, but `&&` has *lower* precedence than `+`. That is why you would need to fully parenthesize your expression in order to force the desired order of operations with only `*` replaced by `&&`.

Replacing both `*` and `+` with `&&` and `||` will keep relative precedence of the two operators the same, so you would end up with the same result.

Comment: Upvoted; I will confess to having stolen your precedence point as I tried, for once, to make my answer comprehensive.

Comment: Do also feel free to borrow my other points in my answer: your answers tend to end up being of a superior quality to mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba Your answer explains the differences from the title of the question, which is more important in the long run - for visitors coming through a search engine hit. In a way, I am making a side point here, that logical and arithmetic operators cannot be used in a mix-and-match fashion. Since that's what OP's been doing, this one point explains the differences for him. For everyone else, the other six points are more relevant.